# asynchronus content in two-column reveal.js presentation

Tags: html, css, iframe, grid, reveal.js

I'd like to have a 2 column reveal.js slide where I can page through the slides in the left-hand column (ColA) while a video plays in the right-hand column (ColB). The slides accompany the video.

I have it laid out on [this page](https://brnco.github.io/DPOE-N-Workshop_IntroCLI-AVTools/webinar.html#/3) but the contents in the iframe/ColA are not large enough to read. I've tried scaling it but it scales the entire containing div, making the two columns overlap, and does not just scale the contents of the iframe.

Another option is to do the slides like normal, where each slide contains a link to the embedded video. My worry there is that every one of the embedded videos will play at once once the page loads because it's a live stream - it seems like that might eat a lot of processing power as my computer tries to play the same embedded live stream in 30 different slides. When moving from Slide1 to Slide2, are embedded videos stopped?

The full git repo for this is [here](https://github.com/brnco/DPOE-N-Workshop_IntroCLI-AVTools/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the iframe will work very well for multiple reasons:

- The scaling problem that you already encountered. iframes are notoriously hard to scale, as the size has to be hardcoded when embedding them.
- The nested presentation will have its own navigation, so it wont be clear where to proceed with the presentation.

You also already anticipated teh next problem - when putting the same video on multiple slides indeed the video will "restart" - first the old video will fade out and then the new copy will fade in. This is because each slide is it's own self-contained HTML element. So this also won't do what you want.

Instead I would propose to use [Fragments](https://revealjs.com/fragments/). Fragments are the way you can have individual elements on a page change without changing the whole slide (commonly used for making bullet points appear).

In your case you can implement your "sub slides" on the left side as individual fragments that appear on top of each other using the css classes `fragment fade-in-then-out` (to make them appear/disappear) and `r-stack` (to make them appear on top of each other). You can see an example on the ["Layout"](https://revealjs.com/layout/#stack) page in the documentation (the second one with cat pictures).

If you put all of your sub-slides as fragments, then you can just have your video embedded as normal on the right and it will play independently from the subslides changing. Once the last sub-slide is passed, the presentation will move on to the next real slide (stopping the video).

Comment: thank you! I wrote a script to read through a JSON file with each "subslide" and got that working, but Fragments looks much nicer.